# Retaining year when grouping by month, in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using MSSQL 2005.

i have a table that counts stats - and the data is stored daily.

what i would like to do - is display a table of data - where the information is grouped by month.

sample data:

```
 id   |   clickDate  |  clicksEmail
-------------------------------------
 1        10/11/2013       2
 2        09/11/2013       1
 3        05/11/2013       4
 4        30/10/2013       4
```

this is what i have now:

```
SELECT  datepart(m,clickDate), sum([clicksEmail]) TotalWeb 
FROM tblCompanyClicks  A WHERE companyID = 1129 
GROUP BY datepart(m,clickDate)
ORDER BY datepart(m,clickDate) DESC
```

which works great.  just that i would also like to display the year - not just the month.
but as soon as i add the year into the SQL, its ruins the aggregate function. I tried using a sub select, but that too didnt seem to work.

This is what i would like displayed:

```
month & year    |     Summary
-------------------------------
  Nov 2013      |      7
  Oct 2013      |      4
```

Assistance appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping like :

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), clickDate, 0) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, clickDate), 
        sum([clicksEmail]) TotalWeb 
FROM tblCompanyClicks  A WHERE companyID = 1129 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), clickDate, 0) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, clickDate)
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), clickDate, 0) + ' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, clickDate) DESC
```

Another way is :

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), clickDate,106),3,20), 
        sum([clicksEmail]) TotalWeb 
FROM tblCompanyClicks  A WHERE companyID = 1129 
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), clickDate,106),3,20)
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), clickDate,106),3,20) DESC
```

For seperate month and year columns you can user DATEPART() function like below :

```
SELECT  DATEPART(YEAR, clickDate) [Year],
        DATEPART(MONTH, clickDate) [Month], 
        sum([clicksEmail]) TotalWeb 
FROM tblCompanyClicks  A WHERE companyID = 1129 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, clickDate),
         DATEPART(MONTH, clickDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(YEAR, clickDate) DESC,
         DATEPART(MONTH, clickDate) DESC
```

Comment: amazing, thanks.
small follow up question. is it possible to get month number and year number in separate columns?

Comment: Yes, you can get it by DATEPART() function like SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) [Month], DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) [Year]

Comment: great. how would that look in the SQL command above, getting columns as such:   `month number | year number  | summary count`?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   DATENAME(month,clickDate) + ' ' + 
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(year,clickDate)), 
         SUM([clicksEmail]) TotalWeb 
FROM     tblCompanyClicks  A 
WHERE    companyID = 1129 
GROUP BY DATENAME(month,clickDate) + ' ' +  
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(year,clickDate))
ORDER BY DATENAME(month,clickDate) + ' ' +  
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(year,clickDate)) DESC
```